# Bash takes an input with special character

Tags: bash

I am writing a simple calculator script with bash

```
#! /bin/bash

arg1=$1
arg2=$2
arg3=$3

case $arg2 in

   "+")
    res=$((arg1+arg3))
    ;;
   "-")
    res=$((arg1-arg3))
    ;;
   '*')
    res=$((arg1*arg3))
    ;;
   "/")
    res=$((arg1/arg3))
    ;;
    *)
     echo "Incrorrect format"
    ;;
esac

echo $res
```

The script call is like

```
$ bash calc.sh 10 * 2
```

The only operation that doesn't work correctly is `*` as the asterisk is a special character. How can I solve this?

The `bash calc.sh 10 * 2` part needs to stay the same. How do I change the script, not the input?

Comment: ```bash calc.sh 10 \* 2``` OR ```bash calc.sh 10 '*' 2``` OR ```bash calc.sh 10 "*" 2```

Comment: Errors belong on stderr: `echo "Incrorrect format" >&2`

Comment: ...albeit you likely want 'Incorrect' for 'Incrorrect' ;)

Comment: "How do I change the script, not the input?" You can't. You have to change the input.

Comment: @2e0byo, "an errrorr occurred while displaying the previous erorrr."

Comment: "You have to change the input" -- this is because your interactive shell will expand `*` into a list of files **before** your script gets invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the wildcard `*` using either of the below options:

```
bash calc.sh 10 \* 2
bash calc.sh 10 '*' 2
bash calc.sh 10 "*" 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `read` in your script to be more convenient like this

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p 'Enter first arg: '  arg1
read -p 'Enter operator: '   arg2
read -p 'Enter second arg: ' arg3

case $arg2 in

   "+")
    res=$((arg1+arg3))
    ;;
   "-")
    res=$((arg1-arg3))
    ;;
   '*')
    res=$((arg1*arg3))
    ;;
   "/")
    res=$((arg1/arg3))
    ;;
    *)
     echo "Incrorrect format"
    ;;
esac

echo $res
```